# extends schema in mongoose and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have some field and it reapet in all of my models .

i create a `BaseSchema` in in other file from my models :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var util = require('util');

function BaseSchema() {
    Schema.apply(this, arguments);

  this.add({
    owner: { type:String },
    updateDate: { type: String },
    updateBy: { type: String },
    deleteDate: { type: String },
    deleteby: { type: String },
    createDate: { type: String },
    createBy: { type: String },
  });
}

util.inherits(BaseSchema, Schema);
```

and i use this `BaseSchema` in `RoleSchema` :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BaseSchema = require("./baseEntity");

const RoleSchema = new BaseSchema.add({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  description: { type: String },
  scurityStamp: { type: String, require: true },
});

RoleSchema.pre('save',()=>{
    scurityStamp='kianoush'
})
mongoose.model('Roles',RoleSchema);
```

but when i run the project it show me this error :

```
 const RoleSchema = new BaseSchema.add({
                   ^

TypeError: BaseSchema.add is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\src\entity\role.js:5:20)
```

**whats the prboem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be simplified as you're basically trying to extend your `BaseSchema`:

```
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';

const BaseSchema = new Schema({
    owner: { type:String },
    updateDate: { type: String },
    updateBy: { type: String },
    deleteDate: { type: String },
    deleteby: { type: String },
    createDate: { type: String },
    createBy: { type: String },
});

const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  ...BaseSchema.obj,
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String },
  scurityStamp: { type: String, required: true },
});

// test
const RoleModel = mongoose.model('roles', RoleSchema);
const role = new RoleModel({ name: 'test', scurityStamp: 'test', owner: 'someOwner', createDate: new Date() });
await role.save();
```

Comment: its not she error to me but not add `BaseSchema` field in collection

Comment: this is nodejs `import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
` this command not for nodejs

Comment: Change it to `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;`

Comment: this error const RoleSchema = new BaseSchema.add({
                   ^

TypeError: BaseSchema.add is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\src\entity\role.js:5:20)

Comment: Yes, this is wrong of course. Please use the exact code I gave you. `new BaseSchema.add` is wrong as it's not a constructor you're calling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217178/discussion-between-eol-and-kianoush-dortaj).